# GraphLab Create Launcher Installation Error Windows: There was an error creating the "gl-env" conda environment

Tags: graphlab

I received the following error when trying to install GraphLab Create on Windows.

```
There was a problem creating the "gl-env" conda environment.  Restart GraphLab Create Launcher.
```

Any advice on how to fix this?

Answer (score 4):

In order to solve the problem I had to slightly modify the

https://turi.com/download/install-graphlab-create-command-line.html.

procedure with the following changes:

Step 1: Download Anaconda2 v4.0.0

Step 2: Install Anaconda
Run Anaconda2 v4.0.0 installer.
Double-click the .exe file to install Anaconda and follow the instructions on the screen.

Step 3: Create conda environment
Create a new conda environment with Python 2.7.x

```
CD anaconda2/scripts/
conda install -n root _license
conda update pip
conda create -n gl-env python=2.7 anaconda=4.0.0
```

Activate the conda environment

```
activate gl-env
```

Step 4: Ensure pip version >= 7
Ensure pip is updated to the latest version
miniconda users may need to install pip first, using `conda install pip`

```
CD anaconda2/envs/gl-env/
conda install pip or conda update pip
```

Install your licensed copy of GraphLab Create

```
pip install --upgrade --no-cache-dir https://get.graphlab.com/GraphLab-Create/2.1/ your registered email address here/your product key here/GraphLab-Create-License.tar.gz
```

Step 6: Ensure installation of IPython and IPython Notebook
Install or update IPython and IPython Notebook

```
conda install ipython-notebook
```

Step 7: Start IPhyton Notebook
Start IPhyton from gl-env

```
ipython notebook
```

Answer (score 1):

Use following command:

```
conda create -n gl-env python=2.7 anaconda
```

instead of:

```
conda create -n gl-env python=2.7 anaconda=4.0.0
```

Note: gl-env can be replaced by any name eg. gbl-env. It does not need to be gl-env only.

Later you can follow the steps from turi.com or the following reference:
[Reference](https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2015/12/started-graphlab-python/)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the work around for this issue right now is to use the command line instructions to install GraphLab Create. Note that these instructions are only for people who have previously tried to install using the GraphLab Create Launcher. If you have not installed any GraphLab products, then you can start at Step 1 of the command line instructions:

1. Go to Control Panel > Programs > Programs and Features.
2. In this panel, uninstall all instances of "GraphLab Create Launcher".
3. Reboot.
4. Reinstall GraphLab Create using the command line method starting at "Option 1: Step 2: Ensure pip version >= 7": https://turi.com/download/install-graphlab-create-command-line.html.

Answer (score 0):

*GraphLab Installation Steps on Windows*:

1. Go to [turi.com](https://turi.com/) **→** **Hover over Coursera Students** **→** **Click on Academic Licenses** **→** **Register** **→** **Check your email**
2. [Download Anaconda2 v4.0.0](https://repo.continuum.io/archive/Anaconda2-4.0.0-Windows-x86_64.exe)
3. Install it
4. Open Anaconda Navigator
5. Create a GraphLab environment using create button at the bottom of the interface, select python version 2.7, name it "gl-env"

   **Environments tab** **→** **Create** **→** **Python version = 2.7** **→** **gl-env**

   [Sample Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CEywQ.png)

N.B: It may take some time

6. Then select gl-env and clik play button, some options will pop up, select terminal

   **gl-env** **→** **Play button** **→** **Terminal**
7. Execute the following command

   `python -m pip install pip==9.0.1`

8.Execute the following command replacing**Your email** and **license** that has been sent to your email:

```
pip install --upgrade --no-cache-dir https://get.graphlab.com/GraphLab-Create/2.1/your email/license/GraphLab-Create-License.tar.gz
```

9. Execute the following command

   `conda install ipython-notebook`
10. Click on **Open with python notebook** on your **gl-env** play button from anaconda navigator
11. Now execute the following command on Jupyter notebook

    `graphlab.get_dependencies()`
12. Then execute

    `import graphlab`

**Hopefully you are all set**